# Looking for function similar to array_map but which the same arg each time to the callback

Tags: php, array-map

As someone who is learning PHP I was experimenting with the arrap_map function. I was hoping that it would pass the same 3rd arg each time through to the called function. As below, this is not the behaviour of array_map. Is there an alternative function I can use to achieve this?

```
$arr = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']];
$args = ['set'];

function mapper($item, $arg){
return $item[] = $arg;
}
$result = array_map('mapper', $arr, $args);
```

only the first element has 'set' as a value

```
 $arr = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']];
$args = ['set', 'set', 'set'];

function mapper($item, $arg){
return $item[]  = $arg;
}

$result = array_map('mapper', $arr, $args);
```

all three elements have 'set' as a value

Comment: And what is the problem/question now?

Comment: I think `array_fill_keys()` is better for what you want to do.

Comment: "pass the 3rd argument through each time?" - and what exactly should it pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incorrect, `$a[$b]` doesn't make any sense. Both variables are strings.

Your output also doesn't make sense, quoting from the manual:

> If more than one argument is passed then the returned array always has
>   integer keys.

---

To answer your question, it's a language design choice.

It could

- pass NULL for missing elements (that was PHP does).
- throw an error if the inputs don't have the same size.
- cycle the smaller inputs.

All these have valid applications and their own problems.

Comment: @AndrewWelch Now after you updated your question it simply comes down to a misunderstanding how `array_map()` works. With `array_map()` you go through each element of every array which you passed to it.

Comment: `echo "$a $b";` :) or `var_dump` if you want to see the `NULL`.

Comment: Ok, so now you removed the text about what it "returns", but it's the *same* nonsensical code. I'm out.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - can you delete your answer, so I can delete the questions please.